# I'm trying to run my vb.net project to another laptop connected to SQL Server 2008

Tags: .net, sql-server

I get this error. Why is my program getting this error, when my friends program does not? He also run his program to other laptop...

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: the solution in sis the error message. did you check that the relevant SQL server instance is accessible?

Comment: My friend and I exporting our same  program to the same laptop..his program run properly but mine was not..we have a same source and version of sql and vb.net..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check and see if SQL Server is started in your windows services (services.msc) then check your firewall settings for port 1433 or just turn it off for your development. Finally see if you can allow remote connections to the program. I

In SSMS right click SQL Server instance -> Properties -> Connections ->  Check the Allow remote connections to this server box.

Finally check your permissions to make sure you have the rights to access your database within SSMS.